# Transform a lengthy json Struct to rows and not columns in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON like this:

```
root
 |--   Apple: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Ripe: long (nullable = true)
 |--   Mango: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Ripe: long (nullable = true)
 |--  Grapes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Raw: long (nullable = true)
 |--  Berry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Not Ripe: long (nullable = true)
 |--  Cherry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Ripe: long (nullable = true)
```

When I try to register this as table on spark, Apple, Mango....Cherry show up as columns and Ripe, Unripe, Raw show up as rows. I have a JSON with more than 50 fruits and vegetables but only 3 options with each: Ripe, Unripe, Raw. So, the method I'm using creates a wide table with just 3 rows.

I'd like to swap it so that Apple, Mango...Cherry show up as rows while Ripe, Raw, Not Ripe as columns. In python, I used transpose under Pandas to easily accomplish this.

Comment: Can you please share how the input data looks like ? This helps understand the question